# Invoke-ResMethod Rest API

Tags: json, powershell, api

This is my first time reaching out on here.

I am trying to create a script for Ivanti Appsense using json code powershell, but i hit an issue

i keep getting a return message "te request is invalid" i am hoping i can get some help
so in powershell this is my code

```
$url = "http://server/path/api/ImmediateTask"
$cred = Get-Credential
 
$body = @"
{
   "id":"the ID",
   "operations" = [
      {
         "windowsSettingsGroupDisplayName": "_Active Setup",
         "operation":{
            "liveSettingsDelete":{
               "deleteRegistry": true,
               "deleteFiles": true,
               "preserveArchives": true
            }
         }
      }
"@
 
 
$request = Invoke-RestMethod  -Method post -Credential $cred -Uri $url -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" 
 
$request
```

however when i run it and use the correct credentials this is my output

[image: output]

Comment: Perhaps you're not supposed to supply the `id` up front when creating a new task?

Comment: Isn't your `$body` missing a closing square brace, and a closing curly brace?

Comment: @scottwtang I just added the closing square because i noticed it myself but it had no effect.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen
The ID is needed because that refers to the specific user you are trying to apply an action too

Comment: Try with `ConvertTo-Json` on `$body` as well, as your `ContentType` is `application/json`

Comment: @scottwang I just tried to add it to the body using $request = Invoke-RestMethod  -Method post -Credential $cred -Uri $url -Body ($body  | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json" but this did not have any effect

Comment: ```"operations" = ["``` is invalid json as well - you're using a ```=``` instead of a ``:```. I think you need to rework how you're generating the json to get some help from PowerShell's parser *before* you call ```Invoke-WebRequest```

Comment: @mclayton Thank you for noticing that i used and = instead of ":" this remained from a test i did earlier. other then that the Json code has been checked over and should be valid. I have also checked the API documentation and couldn't find any issues. i have also tried to change Invoke-RestMethod to Invoke-WebRequest. this also did not help me.  i hope you do have some more suggestions

Comment: @HendrikHoppentocht - in that case, can you update your question with the valid json. so that the errors in the current text don't distract from the actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the whole answer to your problem, but one issue is you're sending invalid json to the API.

You can use PowerShell's features to generate the json string programmatically rather than do it by hand yourself. This way PowerShell will give you more meaningful error messages if your syntax is invalid, rather than waiting for the API to give you a generic "An error has occurred" message:

```
$data = [ordered] @{
    "id"         = "the ID"
    "operations" = @(
        [ordered] @{
            "windowsSettingsGroupDisplayName" = "_Active Setup"
            "operation"                       = [ordered] @{
                "liveSettingsDelete" =  [ordered] @{
                    "deleteRegistry"   = $true
                    "deleteFiles"      = $true
                    "preserveArchives" = $true
                }
            }
        }
    )
};

$json = ConvertTo-Json $data -Depth 99;

write-host $json
#{
#  "id": "the ID",
#  "operations": [
#    {
#      "windowsSettingsGroupDisplayName": "_Active Setup",
#      "operation": {
#        "liveSettingsDelete": {
#          "deleteRegistry": true,
#          "deleteFiles": true,
#          "preserveArchives": true
#        }
#      }
#    }
#  ]
#}
```

`$data` is basically building a nested hashtable structure, which PowerShell (and your IDE) will warn you about if you have missing brakcets, unclosed quotes, etc.

`ConvertTo-Json` converts this structured object into a json string.

You might still get errors from your API after doing this, but at least you'll know your json is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the info. With it i was able to solve my issue